# Why was it so easy to defeat Toneri, Kinshiki and Momoshiki?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Toneri had somewhat the same Goal as Madara. Madara gained Hagoromo's Power and Toneri, Hamura's. The both powers are, I believe equivalent.

***Sharingan >> Rinnegan = Byakugan >> Tenseigan***

He who awakens the Rinnegan, shall receive the Powers of Hagoromo and he who awakens the Tenseigan shall receive the Powers of Hamura. Which is exactly what happened. BUT... Toneri had the Power of Hamura, who has the equivalent Power as Hagoromo... Then, how was Naruto able to finish Toneri's Tenseigan (and the Powers of Hamura) away with one blow?? + just in Nine Tails Mode, without his Six Paths Powers.. It just doesn't add up.

Now.. let's move to the Movie Boruto:

Kinshiki and Momoshiki are **very** powerful beings... Momoshiki even has 3 Rinnegan (One in his Forehead, and one in each palm) and has also the equivalent, if not greater Power to those of Kaguya.... how the hell was he defeated by only Boruto (a child)? While it took **Naruto & Sasuke** to seal away (not defeat) Kaguya and they both had the Six Paths Powers, while Boruto had none whatsoever.

Comment: It wasn't so easy I guess. It took both Indra and Ashura's reincarnations (Naruto and Sasuke) + other 4 kage to beat them.

Comment: I would say Sharingan = Byakugan < Mangekyou < Eternal Mangekyou < Rinnegan <= Tenseigan

Comment: @arcane I guess we haven't experienced/seen Hamura's descendants as much as Hagomoro's... but it would've been awesome to if there were somewhat the same stages of the byakugan.. ex.: Byakugan < Level 2 Byakugan  < Level 3 Byakugan < Tenseigan ... but i understand what you mean

Comment: Plot hole maybe? I means there's a lot of them in Naruto, so you shouldn't be surprised if it is.

Comment: Since Toneri is a character from Naruto the movie, then  the main reason would be to keep the movie from being too long, which is tied to production cost.

Comment: Yah exactly. They need to able to kill the villain by the end of the movie. Well, that's the pragmatic answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naruto and Sasuke during Boruto saga are way stronger than the version in the war arc, so any actual threat that is Kaguya or even just slightly above her is not gonna do much against them and did so because they were nerfed in the movie.

As for how Boruto's rasengan finished the enemy is because Naruto used his chakra to charge it and you can expect that his rasengan is going to be over powered.

These are reasons I believe so, as you can't expect them to be same level when they fought Kaguya as they did not have experience with their power and it's already shown in this series and many other that you become more powerful as you grow older until certain age.

Comment: Naruto also only had half of Kurama in him during Kaguya, because half of it was in her. After the final battle, he got both halves combined within him, so had a whole Kurama for Tonrei and momoshiki. That is a significant boost in power.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, neither of them were easy. It took 5 kages + Sasuke to defeat Momoshiki & Kinshiki. As for Toneri reducing production cost's technical factors:

1. Transplanted Byakugan and evolved it into Tenseigan minutes before starting to fight Naruto. Even assuming he knew about its powers, he won't have instant mastery over it.
2. He was fighting BSM Naruto even if part of Kyuubi was separated, he was actually powering golem that it was fighting.
3. Was trying to ram Moon into Earth all while fighting Naruto.

Also, people mostly forget to mention that guy is in similar age group as Naruto & co. So, no help there. Well, he seems quite knowledgeable (Otsutsuki factor), but still no extra time to develop chakra.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Naruto and Sasuke were vastly inferior in power to when they fought Kaguya. They no longer had Six Paths power, Naruto could only use Kurama, and Sasuke Susanoo and he only had 1 arm left! It's just that Kaguya is vastly stronger than the other members of her clan. In fact, she's vastly stronger than all other characters in Naruto, she is the god of the Naruto verse after all.

The whole Momoshiki greater threat was hype-crap. They got beat by a simple large Rasengan made by Boruto and a weakened Naruto on his base-form while Kaguya took 9 Rasenshurikens at once. She didn't even absorb them, she just tanked them.

By feats, Momo and Kinshiki were below Madara, let alone Kaguya, who Sasuke stated on his thoughts to be far stronger than Madara.

Answer (score -1):

Two reasons:

1. Byakugan is weaker than the Sharingan
2. Toneri was not a Hyuuga before he started his world domination. Madara was actually an Uchiha, therefore he had the immediate access to all Sharingan powers. Toneri didn't have immediate access to Byakugan. Not to mention the fact that the Hyuuga kept the Byakugan a heavily guarded secret. So much to the fact that they had to create a seal for the branch family. One reason Sharingan was so easy to just obtain, is that the Uchiha didn't put in extra effort to guard their eyes. That is because only those who have a strong will can have the Sharingan. Sharingan is much much harder to obtain than Byakugan because you are not born with it.